# Mongodb aggregation limit occurrence of individual field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a list of blog posts with category and timestamp. Now if I'd like to order them chronologically but limit the occurrence of each category to, say, *only 3 posts per category*, a regular $group doesn't seem like the right approach. Same goes for topN since that groups those posts per category but I'm losing the chronological list.

Comment: please provide some sample dataset it will help full to discover the problem and aggregate the queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use `"$group"` with `"$topN"` and then, for example, follow that with another `"$group"`, sorting, `"$unwind"`, and `"$replaceWith"`.

N.B.: This will give the earliest posts.  If you want the latest posts, you can adjust the sort order.

```js
db.blogPosts.aggregate([
  { // get max 3 items from category
    // sorted by timestamp
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$category",
      "postsTop3": {
        "$topN": {
          "n": 3,
          "sortBy": {"timestamp": 1},
          "output": "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // aggregate all top3's
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "posts": {"$push": "$postsTop3"}
    }
  },
  { // sort them all by timestamp
    "$set": {
      "posts": {
        "$sortArray": {
          "input": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$posts",
              "initialValue": [],
              "in": {
                "$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]
              }
            }
          },
          "sortBy": {"timestamp": 1}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$posts"},
  {"$replaceWith": "$posts"}
])
```

Try it [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W-8ocXBCRq8).